# CSS: Using display grid, is it possible to make one of the cells a different size without affecting the other cells size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Calculator website and I want the numpad to have a specific format. I want the "0" and "ENTER" key to be larger by expanding them horizontally and vertically, respectfully. Upon manipulating the size of one cell in the grid, all the cells within that row resized accordingly which is not how I would like the cells to behave. Is it possible to resize one grid w/o affecting the others?

**Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/rintendou/pen/gOeNbaa**

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* background-color: #676767; */
}

.app {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 1%;
    background-color: #676767;

    height: 600px;
    width: 450px;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 2em;
    gap: 2em;
}

.display {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;

    height: 75px;
    width: 400px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    gap: 20px;
}

#button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?vfquery=fira">
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="display">
                    display
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is you are looking

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* background-color: #676767; */
}

.app {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 1%;
    background-color: #676767;

    height: 600px;
    width: 450px;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 2em;
    gap: 2em;
}

.display {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;

    height: 75px;
    width: 400px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    gap: 20px;
}

#button {

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.zero {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.enter {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?vfquery=fira">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="display">
                display
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button" class="enter">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button" class="zero">
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
                <button id="button">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for could you explain what you did? Or any documentation that relates to what you did?

Comment: I added two class to the button zero and enter. You are already using grid. So I redefine the grid size in CSS using those two class.